# Obsidian - не подсвечиает collout

Tags: редактор, редактор-текста, текстовый-редактор

подскажите почему у меня не работает подсветка коллаута, тема стандартная установлена.

Код вот такой

```
> [!info]Установка через PECL
> $ sudo apt install php-pear
> $ pecl install xdebug
```

Почему у меня этот блок отображается как цитата, а не коллаут?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решилось добавлением пробела после закрывающей квадратной скобки ]